# Can't assign base64 string to a class property - javascript

Tags: javascript

my goal is to make an upload of an image, I have a method whre I want to assign the base64 string to the class method file, the problem is that when I try to get the value in the property, the result is undefined and I don't understand why. I whould like to assign the string to the property _file or return it in the method.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
 <body>
    <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" />
      <input id="btn" type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
<script>
  class File {
    constructor() {
      this._file;
    }
    setFile(file) {
      const input = document.querySelector(file).files[0];
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(input);

      reader.onload = function () {
        this._file = reader.result.split(",")[1];
        console.log(this._file);
      };
    }
    getFile() {
      console.log(this._file);
    }
  }

  document
    .getElementById("btn")
    .addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      const file = new File();
      file.setFile("input[type=file]");
      file.getFile();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: my suggestion: Come up with another class name then `File` it already exist in the global scope. and don't use base64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two subtle mistakes:

```
reader.onload = function() {
    this._file = reader.result.split(",")[1];
    console.log(this._file);
};
```

Here, the **this** keyword is not pointing to your File instance, it is pointing to **reader**. This can be resolved by using [arrow functions](https://hackernoon.com/javascript-es6-arrow-functions-and-lexical-this-f2a3e2a5e8c4):

```
reader.onload = () => {
    this._file = reader.result.split(",")[1];
    console.log(this._file);
};
```

Now, the **this** keyword is pointing to your File instance. Now you have another problem: **readAsDataURL** is asynchronous, that is, it does all the job in the background, like AJAX, without blocking the main thread. So if you have:

```
file.setFile("input[type=file]");
file.getFile();
```

Nothing guarantees that `file.getFile()` will print the updated value for `_file`, because you don't know if the reader has finished its job or not. So my recommendation is using a callback:

```
class File {
    constructor() {
        // ...
    }
    setFile(file, callback) {
        const input = document.querySelector(file).files[0];
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = () => { // when reader has finished
            this._file = reader.result.split(",")[1]; // update _file property
            callback(); // execute callback
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input);
    }
    getFile() {
        console.log(this._file);
    }
}
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const file = new File();
    file.setFile("input[type=file]", function() {
        // put here all the code that uses the file variable
        file.getFile(); 
    });
});
```

**LIVE DEMO**

```js
class File {
    constructor() {
        // ...
    }
    setFile(file, callback) {
        const input = document.querySelector(file).files[0];
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = () => { // when reader has finished
            this._file = reader.result.split(",")[1]; // update _file property
            callback(); // execute callback
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input);
    }
    getFile() {
        console.log(this._file);
    }
}
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const file = new File();
    file.setFile("input[type=file]", function() {
        // put here all the code that uses the file variable
        file.getFile(); 
    });
});
```

```html
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" />
  <input id="btn" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```